# Como pegar todos os valores selecionados em um DataGridView?

Tags: c#, datagridview

Estou tentando pegar todos os valores selecionados em um `DataGridView` e adicionar a um `IList<Object>` mas exibe uma excessão. Como fazer isso ?

Estou tentando assim.

```
IList<Modulo> lista = gridModulos.SelectedRows.Cast<Modulo>().ToList();
```

Comment: Como esses itens estão selecionados? E qual a mensagem de erro que está dando? Manda mais detalhes prf.

Comment: @DeRamon resolvi o problema. Segui esse exemplo: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.databounditem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @FernandoPaiva Você pode adicionar uma resposta com a solução(`código`) do seu problema resolvido, ajudaria futuros usuários com o mesmo problema.

Answer (score 1):

Penso que isto possa ajudar

```
List<Modulo> lst = new List<Modulo>();

foreach (DataGridViewRow gridRow in dataGridView.Rows)
{
    Modulo modulo = new Modulo();

    foreach (DataGridViewCell gridCell in gridRow.Cells)
    {
        if (gridCell.Displayed == false)
        {
             continue;
        }

        // aqui tem acesso à linha (gridRow) e á coluna (gridCell.Value)
        // pode usar reflection para fazer set à propriedade dinamicamente.
        modulo.propriedade = gridCell.Value; 
    }

    lst.Add(modulo)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá, se você estiver alimentando o dataGridView utilizando a propriedade 
datasource, você pode utilizar esse código:

```
IList<Modulo> lista = gridModulos.SelectedRows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Select(p => (Modulo)p.DataBoundItem).ToList();
```